# Getting correct Time Difference with Join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I am having some trouble getting time difference using join for mysql. I played with min and max for Time difference, but can't get it to work. Thank you for any help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ab.record AS `record`,
    ab.timeIn AS `timeIN`,
    de.timeOut AS `timeOut`,
    TIMEDIFF(de.timeOut,ab.timeIn) AS `timeDifference`,
    ab.description AS `description`,

    FROM 
     TableA ab
    INNER JOIN TableB de ON de.record = ab.record 

    GROUP BY `timeIn`, `description`
```

This is TableA

```
+----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| id | record | timeIn              | description |
+----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| 1  | 9      | 2017-03-25 12:41:59 | productA    |
+----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| 2  | 11     | 2017-03-25 15:00:35 | productB    |
+----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| 4  | 11     | 2017-03-25 12:42:00 | productB    |
+----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| 5  | 14     | 2017-03-25 12:42:00 | productC    |
+----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
```

This is TableB

```
+----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| id | record | timeOut             | description |
+----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| 1  | 11     | 2017-03-25 15:10:10 | productB    |
+----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| 2  | 9      | 2017-03-25 12:47:17 | productA    |
+----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| 4  | 11     | 2017-03-25 12:47:17 | productB    |
+----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| 5  | 14     | 2017-03-25 12:47:18 | productC    |
+----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Combined Table with MySQL Time Difference

```
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| id | record | timeIn              | timeOut             | timeDifference | description |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| 1  | 9      | 2017-03-25 12:41:59 | 2017-03-25 12:47:17 | 00:05:18       | productA    |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| 2  | 11     | 2017-03-25 12:42:00 | 2017-03-25 15:10:10 | 02:28:10       | productB    |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| 4  | 14     | 2017-03-25 12:42:00 | 2017-03-25 12:47:18 | 00:05:18       | productC    |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| 5  | 11     | 2017-03-25 15:00:35 | 2017-03-25 15:10:10 | 00:09:35       | productB    |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

What is desired result:

```
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| id | record | timeIn              | timeOut             | timeDifference | description |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| 1  | 9      | 2017-03-25 12:41:59 | 2017-03-25 12:47:17 | 00:05:18       | productA    |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| 2  | 11     | 2017-03-25 12:42:00 | 2017-03-25 12:47:17 | 00:05:18       | productB    |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| 4  | 14     | 2017-03-25 12:42:00 | 2017-03-25 12:47:18 | 00:05:18       | productC    |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| 5  | 11     | 2017-03-25 15:00:35 | 2017-03-25 15:10:10 | 00:09:35       | productB    |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: So if record and description are equal you want to have your query know to use timeIn and timeOut in order? put a where clause in that TimeIn has to be less than timeOut

Comment: why you are using group by without aggregation function . ??

Comment: @ Edward That might work, I have to try it out.

Comment: @scaisEdge I was trying out a method to get rid of duplicates was the main  reason

Answer (score 1):

if you have more that one value for each  record
 you should use aggregation function as min and mx for get the firts and last value then you should group bu

```
SELECT 
    ab.record AS `record`,
    min(ab.timeIn )AS `timeIN`,
    max(de.timeOut ) AS `timeOut`,
    TIMEDIFF(max(de.timeOut),min(ab.timeIn)) AS `timeDifference`,
    ab.description AS `description`,

    FROM 
     TableA ab
    INNER JOIN TableB de ON de.record = ab.record 

    GROUP BY record
```

Comment: Ok, I ran this piece and found it gives me 3 entries but unfortunately not what I am looking for.  The thing is regarding the record 11, I am not sure if there is a way with min, max to tie those correctly without other information.

Answer (score 1):

No need of having any group by function over there. Because you need all records with time in and out.But you need to have max difference to get required result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ab.record AS `record`,
    ab.timeIn AS `timeIN`,
    de.timeOut AS `timeOut`,
    TIMEDIFF(de.timeOut,ab.timeIn) AS `timeDifference`,
    ab.description AS `description`
 FROM 
     TableA ab
    INNER JOIN TableB de ON de.record = ab.record and de.timeOut between ab.timeIn and 
date_add(ab.timeIn,INTERVAL 2 HOUR);
```

Here I have taken max of 2 hours between in and out time.

You can do one more thing we can take row_number over that record and time with order by time so we can easily get difference because data will be order by time and record.

Below is the code for the same.

```
select distinct ti.record AS record, ti.timeIn AS timeIN,to.timeOut as timeOut, ti.description AS description, TIMEDIFF(to.timeOut,ti.timeIn) AS timeDifference,
 from (SELECT ab.record AS record, ab.timeIn AS timeIN,ab.description AS description,
@row_num:=if(@record_rn=record,@row_num+1,1) rownum
 FROM TableA ab ,
 (select @row_num:=1 ) x,
 (select @record_rn:='' ) y 
 order by ab.record ace ab.timeOut desc) ti
 inner join 
 (SELECT de.record AS record,de.timeOut AS timeOut,de.description, AS description,
 @row_num:=if(@record_rn=record,@row_num+1,1) rownum2
 FROM TableB de,
 (select @row_num:=1 ) x,
 (select @record_rn:='' ) y 
 order by de.record ace de.timeOut desc) to on (ti.rownum=to.rownum and ti.record=to.record)
```

Comment: Ya this way gets me all entries with correct  data for this instance, but in other instances it will be incorrect unfortunately as sometimes the products may be 1 hour instead of two or whatever number. I will keep playing around with it.